# How do I find my DNS server code?

Tags: wi-fi, mobile-data, wifi-hotspot, dns

I'm currently trying to get my Nintendo Switch to connect to my phone's hotspot, but it comes up with a DNS error. I later figured out, that I need to put in the DNS server manually
However the problem with this is I can't find my hotspot's DNS anywhere, can somebody help? I'm using a Samsung Galaxy A20e (Version 10)

Comment: Honestly, it doesn't matter what it is... Use a public DNS server like Google (8.8.8.8/8.8.4.4), Cloudflare (1.1.1.1/1.0.0.1), or any other one you like, there are literally hundreds of public DNS servers. Otherwise, if your phone is connected over the mobile data network, you will need a special app or access to the terminal to determine that, if the connection is WiFi, it should be listed right in the Settings for the WiFi network you are actively connected to in your phone. DNS is just a service running on a server, there isn't a special code, you just need the IP address of the server.